# Plots in for loop of R markdown not working

Tags: r, for-loop, r-markdown

I am trying to use `for` loop in `R markdown` but it is not working for some reason. Here is the code:

````
```{r}
for (i in 1:length(endothelial_ids)) {
    id <- endothelial_ids[i]
    sym <- neuron_symbols[i]
    VlnPlot(object = seurat_object, features.plot = id, do.return = TRUE) + labs(title = sym)
    renderPlot({
      fp <- FeaturePlot(object = seurat_object, features.plot = id, cols.use = c("grey", "blue"),
                            reduction.use = "tsne", do.return = TRUE)
      lapply(fp, function(x){x + labs(title = sym)})
    })
}
```
````

Without `for` loop the code is working and the generated `.html` report file looks good.

In the console I see several warnings:

> output file: /private/var/folders/hq/5ygqq7yn2hd0ln4kznxvx5j80000gn/T/Rtmpj7bedl/cell_type_assignments.knit.md
>
> Warning in file.rename(from, to) :
>     cannot rename file '/private/var/folders/hq/5ygqq7yn2hd0ln4kznxvx5j80000gn/T/Rtmpj7bedl/file613d370b37d8_files/figure-html' to '/private/var/folders/hq/5ygqq7yn2hd0ln4kznxvx5j80000gn/T/Rtmpj7bedl//private/var/folders/hq/5ygqq7yn2hd0ln4kznxvx5j80000gn/T/Rtmpj7bedl/file613d370b37d8_files/figure-html', reason 'No such file or directory'
>   Warning in file.rename(from, to) :
>     cannot rename file '/private/var/folders/hq/5ygqq7yn2hd0ln4kznxvx5j80000gn/T/Rtmpj7bedl//private/var/folders/hq/5ygqq7yn2hd0ln4kznxvx5j80000gn/T/Rtmpj7bedl/file613d370b37d8_files/figure-html' to '/private/var/folders/hq/5ygqq7yn2hd0ln4kznxvx5j80000gn/T/Rtmpj7bedl/file613d370b37d8_files/figure-html', reason 'No such file or directory'
>
> Output created: /private/var/folders/hq/5ygqq7yn2hd0ln4kznxvx5j80000gn/T/Rtmpj7bedl/file613d370b37d8.html

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

If I wrap `VlnPlot` in `print()` function, it draws it, but not `FeaturePlot`:

```
  print(VlnPlot(object = seurat_object, features.plot = id, do.return = TRUE) + labs(title = sym))
  print(renderPlot({
  fp <- FeaturePlot(object = seurat_object, features.plot = id, cols.use = c("grey", "blue"),
                            reduction.use = "tsne", do.return = TRUE)
  lapply(fp, function(x){x + labs(title = sym)})
  }))
```

And in place of the `FeaturePlot` I see the following in the report:

[image]

If I remove `renderPlot()` function and wrap `lapply()` in `print()`, it is printing me two plots instead of one: with the original wrong title and with the final correct one. So, I need a way to avoid printing the original one that happens just from the code:

```
fp <- FeaturePlot(object = seurat_object, features.plot = id, cols.use = c("grey", "blue"),
                            reduction.use = "tsne", do.return = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to wrap `FeaturePlot` in the `print` function?